# bash: Multiple if statements is there a smarter way?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have used multiple if statements to query a CDR_Rate and if its above a threshold send a SNMP trap. If its a new trap, create a alarm flag(CDR_PUSH_A) & Send SNMP trap.
When the script runs again and the threshold is still crossed and the flag is already set. Do not send another trap.

If the threshold has cleared and the flag exists, remove the flag and send a clear snmp trap. 
If there is no threshold crossed do nothing.

```
if [[ $CDR_PUSH -gt 100  &&  ! -e $DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A ]]; then
    touch $DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A;
    echo "Send Trap"
elif [[ $CDR_PUSH -lt 100 && -e $DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A ]]; then
    rm $DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A;
    echo "Clear Trap"
else
    echo "No Alert"
fi
```

The above script works as required.

Just want to know if there is a smarter way to perform the same function?
As I have to do the same command for multiple variables.

Thanks

Comment: Just a thought - you don't do anything if CDR_PUSH is exactly 100...

Comment: I know, I thought that too when I looked at it. I'll change one of them to -le or -ge.

Comment: How many variables?  (Which MIB, for context?) Do variables have different thresholds?

Answer (score 1):

The logic looks ok, wrap it in a function for flexibility

```
#
# $1 = CDR_rate
# $2 = threshold value
# $3 = flag file
#
check_thresh()
{
  if [[ $1 -gt $2 && ! -e $3 ]]; then
      touch -- "$3"
      echo "Send Trap"
  elif [[ $1 -le $2 && -e $3 ]]; then
      rm -- "$3"
      echo "Clear Trap"
  else
      echo "No Alert"
  fi
}

check_thresh "$CDR_PUSH" 100 "$DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A"
check_thresh "$something" 50 "$DIR6/something_Z"
```

Answer (score 1):

Break up your code in smaller chunks, like this:

```
threshold_exceeded() {
  [[ $CDR_PUSH -gt 100 ]] 
}

clear_trap() {
  rm $DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A
  echo "Clear Trap"
}

send_trap() {
  touch $DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A
  echo "Send Trap"
}

was_trap_sent_before() {
  [[ -e $DIR5/CDR_PUSH_A ]]
}

check_for_alert() {
  if threshold_exceeded; then
    was_trap_sent_before || send_trap
    return
  fi

  if ! threshold_exceeded; then
    was_trap_sent_before && clear_trap
    return
  fi
}
```

You can then parameterise `check_for_alert()` with *event name*, *value*, and *threshold*.